# How does iPhone encryption work?

Tags: iphone, password, encryption

I am trying to figure out how iPhone encryption works on iPhone 7.

From my understanding there are 2 scenarios:

Encryption is active by default (even without a lock screen password) and the encryption key is encrypted by a system default password.

or

Encryption on iPhone is not active by default and only active if a lock screen password is set.

Which of these (or none of these) is true for iPhone? I tried researching this myself but kept getting different answers.

Where can I find more complete information?

Comment: It's usually prefered to *edit* questions which are on hold instead of reposting them. Anyway, what kind of answers did you find, where do the differ? LInks might be useful here.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Does-resetting-your-iPhone-to-factory-settings-actually-delete-everything-on-the-device-or-is-there-anything-that-can-be-recovered and https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/4nucna/is_the_iphone_fully_encrypted_by_default_or_does/

Comment: Those two links above are what I was able to find but they didn't really answer Mt question well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption on the iPhone is "active by default" as you call it, it is however not done with a "system default password". So basically you have set up 2 options to choose from, and neither is the correct one here.

You can find complete information about encryption on the iPhone on [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sece3bee0835/1/web/1). Remember to click the "Next" link at the bottom to go through the multi-page document.

For more specific information, look at this [subpage](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secb010e978a/1/web/1), which states:

> If a file isn’t assigned a Data Protection class, it is still stored
> in encrypted form (as is all data on an iOS and iPadOS device)

Comment: This link describes encryoption of Mac computers, not iPhone, which the article specifically delineates. Where can I find info on iPhone encryption? Can you elaborate on your understanding of default encryption?

Comment: Read the text again - it does describe encryption of iPhone and iPads - not only Mac computers. What part of my understanding do you need elaboration on? - I.e. could you elaborate on why you're asking the question, this might make it easier for me to understand, what you need explained further.

Comment: All the article says is ios devices use data protection and that's it. It then goes on to describe in detail how Mac computers are encrypted which is different than iphone per the article. Was there a different article I was supposed to see? You said that both of my scenarios are incorrect. Could you elaborate on how the correct scenario goes?

Comment: The security of the iPhone cannot be explained on a single page. You need to click the "Next" link to go to the next page to read through the whole "book".

Comment: As far as I understand your question here, you want to understand if data on the iPhone is encrypted no matter if you have set a "lock screen password" (usually called a passcode) or not. And answer is yes, data on the phone is encrypted in either case.

Comment: Here's a direct link to one of the "Next" pages: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secb010e978a/1/web/1      It specifically says: "If a file isn’t assigned a Data Protection class, it is still stored in encrypted form (as is all data on an iOS and iPadOS device)"

Comment: So if no lock screen password was set and the device was factory reset, all the data before factory reset should still be encrypted and the encryption key is gone?

Comment: Yes, that data can no longer be retrieved.

Comment: Do you know generation of iPhone this was implemented? Thank you for sending me that link.

Comment: Which generation do you have?

Comment: I had a 7 but I wanted to see if an expert on here knew which generation. Some internet sources say 3gs, others say 4 or later so I was a bit confused on that.

Comment: That depends on what your question really is about. Are you just asking the data is encrypted, or are you also interested in whether or not that encryption is easy to break? And in which scenarios? I’ll look the generation up depending on your answer here

Comment: Btw: Please mark this answer as accepted if you got your original question answered.

Comment: I guess in terms of the data protection feature and all files being stored in encrypted form even if data protection class is not assigned, when or what generation was this implemented. And could you tell me how to mark as accepted?

Comment: You can mark it as accepted by clicking the big checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: It was implemented with the iPhone 3GS, so that's back in 2009.